# node express returns "Cannot Get" other solutions/ code not working. file upload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

**tldr**

Ok i've been trying to get a file upload server working for a few days now and evrything i try just returns cannot get.
i'm currently trying the setup below but it is not working

**code**

here is server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const upload = require("./upload");
const cors = require("cors");

var router = express.Router();
var app = express();

const server = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

server.use(cors(corsOptions));

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Express" });
});

server.post("/upload", upload);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Below is upload.js

```
const IncomingForm = require("formidable").IncomingForm;

module.exports = function upload(req, res) {   var form = new IncomingForm();

  form.on("file", (field, file) => {
    // Do something with the file
    // e.g. save it to the database
    // you can access it using file.path
    console.log("thisno werk");   });   form.on("end", () => {
    res.json();   });   form.parse(req); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's mean `server` as the result of the `const server = require('express')();`, and `router` as the result of `const router = require('express').Router();`.

`server` is an instance of your Express server while `router` is an instance of API endpoints router. You don't only need to write your router `router.get();`, but you also need to set the appropriate files (so-called controllers) for handling API requests.

So your code should have this line: `server.use('/', yourController);` or simply `server.get('/', handlingFunction);` if you don't have API sections.

However, if you use routers, then you need the first variant.
Your `POST /upload` method works great because it's configured on the app level. But you need to fix your `GET /` method because it's configured on the router level that is unused in your app.

Source: [Express routing](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html)

Comment: i dont understand. what is intended with your controller or handeling functions?

the only thing i need need the server to do is  safe the file in a folder.
i dont need anything else.

Comment: if i add 
function handlingFunction() {
  console.log("bananen");
}
 and 
server.get("/", handlingFunction);

i stil get cannot get /

Comment: @NicTanghe as I can see from your edited post, you have `app` and `server` variables, that are doing the same. However, different parts of your code work with different variables. You create express server and start http server with `app`. So you need to use `app.use()`, `app.listen()`, `app.get()`, `app.post()` etc. You do not  need `server` and `router` variables.

Comment: I think the server is actualy working but erytime i submit a file if i check in the network tab the formdata value is null.

Should i ask a new uestion ?

Comment: @NicTanghe this issue is not related to the original question, so I think "yes, you need to ask a new question".

Comment: they decidet i'm no longer allowed to ask anything and made it impossible for me to fix so yeah i gave up on js for now.